# Keeping a Footer DIV at the bottom of a page

Tags: css, html, footer, sticky-footer

I'm developing a responsive site and I'm trying to keep a DIV positioned at the bottom of the page no matter the width of the browser window that is being used. I've tried the "Sticky Footer" method "http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/" but it requires you to define a height for the footer and the footer's height changes as the browser's width is resized.

Are there any other methods that can be used where you don't have to define the footer's height?

Answer (score 4):

is that what you need?

```
#footer { position: fixed: bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/5uMj4/)

Answer (score 0):

change height to min-height. Should work. http://jsfiddle.net/Mrhh3/